# Array declaration: Parenthesis after Name or Type

Tags: arrays, vb.net, syntax

In VB.NET there are two ways to declare an array without initialization

1.

```
Dim Foo() As Integer
```

2.

```
Dim Foo As Integer()
```

I noticed that but never really cared about it and sometimes used the first and sometimes the second syntax.
**Now I wonder if both methods are really identical.  Which one should I use?**

Looking at the IL code in ILSpy I see that

```
Private d1() As Integer
Private d2 As Integer()
```

results in

```
.field private int32[] d1
.field private int32[] d2
```

meaning that they are both identical.

Is this always the case? Why are there two ways to write the same code?

Comment: I assume it's due to backwards compatibility or the preference of developers which are familiar with `VB6`. I prefer the second way, it's more the .NET way(f.e `int[]`). I always have to think about whether the former is an array or just an `Integer` or even a method that returns an `Integer`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: It's more the C# way - not sure what you mean by ".NET way". (Then there's C++/CLI, which is .NET, and that's totally different, not to mention F#).